# Why doesn't my Selenium session stay logged in?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I'm working on using selenium to sign into GitHub and create a repository. A similar project that I had found, after login used "https://github.com/new" to go to the repo creation page. However, when I try to do that, it returns to an empty login page with the following url: "https://github.com/login?return_to=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fnew".

I'm pretty lost and haven't found a good reason yet for why this would be happening.

PS. This is connected to a shell script, but the shell script is doing what it's supposed to so I didn't attach that code along with the Python that's being troublesome.

```
import sys 
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Safari()

def createProj():
    folder_name = str(sys.argv[0])
    browser.get("https://github.com/login")
    try:
        login_button = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='login_field']")[0]
        login_button.click()
        login_button.send_keys("Insert email here")

        pass_button = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='password']")[0]
        pass_button.click()
        pass_button.send_keys("Insert password here")

        submit_button = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='login']/form/div[4]/input[9]")[0]
        submit_button.click()

    except:
        print("You're already signed in, no need to log in.")

    browser.get("https://github.com/new")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    createProj()
```

Comment: Just an FYI, I have also tried using the xpath of the <a> to get to the new repo page, rather than getting GitHub.com/new, and ran into issues there with it finding and clicking the element which is why I tried the get("https://github.com/new").

Comment: it's possible the .get is happening before the login completes on the server side.  Try putting in a sleep/wait.